# Django. Как правиьно написать фильтр по текущему пользователю?

Tags: django, request, django-admin, users, django-filter

В приложении listings есть таблица Listing:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Риэлтор')
    region = models.CharField(default="Чуйская", max_length=100, verbose_name='Область')
    city = models.CharField(default="Бишкек", max_length=100, verbose_name='Город')
    district = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Район')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Адрес')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание') 
    stage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Этажность')
    rooms = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Количество комнат')   
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Гараж')
    sqmt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Площадь')
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Основное фото')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 1')
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 2')
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 3')
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 4')
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 5')
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 6')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публично')
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
```

В приложении realtors есть модель Realtor:

```
class Realtor(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь', related_name='realtor')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Имя')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Телефон')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Email')
    is_mvp = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Реэлтор месяца')
    hire_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата приёма на работу')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Риэлтор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Риэлторы'
```

В приложении accounts есть функция, которая в личном кабинете должна выводить объявления только текущего пользователя, когда он в системе:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from listings.models import Listing
from realtors.models import Realtor

def dashboard(request):
  listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(user_name=request.user)

  paginator = Paginator(listings, 6)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)

  context = {
    'listings': paged_listings
  }
  return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```

Как правильно прописать вот это фильтр, чтобы всё работало, чтобы выводились объявления текущего пользователя:

```
listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(user_name=request.user)
```

На данный момент такая ошибка:

Cannot resolve keyword 'user_name' into field. Choices are: address, city, description, district, garage, id, is_published, list_date, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, photo_4, photo_5, photo_6, photo_main, price, realtor, realtor_id, region, rooms, sqmt, stage, title

Кому не сложно, помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как пользователь указывается не в моделе `Listing`, а в `Realtor` - правильным вариантом будет использование *reverse relations*:

`Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(realtor__user_name=request.user)`

Обратите внимание на **2 подчеркивания** между `realtor` и `user_name` в фильтре.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
user_name = User.objects.get(user_name = request.user)
listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(realtor = user_name)
```

Comment: ValueError at /accounts/dashboard
Cannot query "admin": Must be "Realtor" instance.

Comment: DoesNotExist at /accounts/dashboard
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_name' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, realtor, user_permissions, username. Если realtor = user_name